# WebDAV Response for a server error

Tags: webdav, caldav

When returning a 500 error response, i want to have a WebDAV XML response like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<D:error xmlns:D="DAV:">
  <D:must-be-checked-in/>
</D:error>"""
```

But instead of `<D:must-be-checked-in/>` i need some property for "Internal server error" which i could not find in any of the related RFCs. Is there a standard webdav response for server errors? Or an empty response body is ok?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything more specific to tell, an empty response body is just fine.

Comment: > If you don't have anything more specific to tell... < I would like to include error description at least